# error en datatable laravel acciones

Tags: php, laravel, datatable

Estoy haciendo una tabla con acciones de `habilitar` y `deshabilitar` al momento de dar click en los botones me manda el url con su respectiva id pero no me llama la funcion en el controlador.

```
Route::get('/admin/votos/all/{id}/deshabiliar','NombrevotosController@deshabiliar');
Route::get('/admin/votos/all/{id}/habilitar','NombrevotosController@habilitar');
```

no se si lo estare colocando mal las **rutas**

```
 @foreach ($proyectos as $proyecto)
<tr>

   <td>{{$proyecto->id}}</td>
  <td>{{$proyecto->nombre}}</td>
  <td>
    @if ($proyecto->acciones == 'Habilitado')
    @if ($proyecto->acciones == 'Habilitado')
    <form action="{{url('/admin/votos/all/'.$proyecto->id.'/deshabilitar')}}" method="post">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="id" value="deshabilitar">
    </form>
    @else  
      <form action="{{url('/admin/votos/all/'.$proyecto->id.'/habilitar')}}" method="post">
     <input  class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="id" value="habilitar">
       </form>
     @endif
  </td>
</tr>
  @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como puedes observar en esta línea:

```html
<form action="{{url('/admin/votos/all/'.$proyecto->id.'/deshabilitar')}}" method="post">
```

Tú formulario está invocando el método `POST` en el endpoint especificado. Sin embargo, en tus rutas las tienes definidas como tipo `GET`:

```php
Route::get('/admin/votos/all/{id}/deshabiliar','NombrevotosController@deshabiliar');
Route::get('/admin/votos/all/{id}/habilitar','NombrevotosController@habilitar');
```

Prueba cambiarlas a `POST`:

```
Route::post('/admin/votos/all/{id}/deshabiliar','NombrevotosController@deshabiliar');
Route::post('/admin/votos/all/{id}/habilitar','NombrevotosController@habilitar');
```

---

#### Observación

Esto no tiene nada que ver con tu pregunta, pero imagino que ambos métodos sirven para cambiar el estado de un objeto entre habilitado/deshabilitado.

Estas acciones podrías realizarlas con una única ruta que sea tipo "**cambiarEstado**", aquí detectas si está habilitada y le cambias el estado y viceversa.

Es solo un consejo para optimizar el código ;)

Comment: jejeje gracias por el consejo , nada sigue sin mandarme a la funcion

Comment: prueba añadir un `dd($request->all());`  en tu controlador para saber qué data te está llegando y si está ingresando.

Comment: dise esto: The page has expired due to inactivity.

Please refresh and try again.

Comment: Ese error es por la [protección CSRF](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf). Añade esto entre `<form>` y `</form>`: `{{ csrf_field() }}`

Comment: si , no habia caido en cuenta de eso gracias

Comment: Que bueno que te haya servido. Buen día

Comment: amigo tengo un problema aqui por tener dos form tendria un problema?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84828/discussion-between-hck-and-ramon-albares).